# How do i add traffic source to a custom event in Google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to track the source/medium (basically UTMs) when a custom event is sent to Google Analytics.

i use `gtag('event', 'sample_event')` to send a custom event to GA. all works as expected.

Except the fact that it tracks all events as having a `(direct)` source regardless of the utms in the URL query.

So i used code to get the UTMs from the url save them in a cookie and try to set the campagin info before sending the event.

like this

```
       const utmObj = {
            campaign_name: utm_campaign,
            campaign_source: utm_source,
            campaign_medium: utm_medium,
            campaign_term: utm_term,
            campaign_content: utm_content,
        };

        window.gtag('set', utmObj);

        window.gtag('config', 'GTM-XXXXX', {
            campaign: {
                name: utm_campaign,
                medium: utm_medium,
                source: utm_source,
                content: utm_content,
                term: utm_term,
            },
        });

        window.gtag('event', eventName, { ...utmObj });
```

None of these seem to work.

Please what am i missing?
How can i add the campaign details to a custom event in a way that Google analytics will recognise?

Comment: You are not attempting to look at them in real time data and you're giving the data enough time to settle? So you see your hits and you have a way to tell they're yours, but no source for them even though you set source in the url?

Comment: @BNazaruk yes exactly. Even though i set a source for them, they still show up as `(Direct)` Yes i see my hits